# Is it necessary to share every underlying folder in a Dropbox shared folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, dropbox, shared-folders

I have one Dropbox (I suppose) shared between my business account / PC and my wife's account / PC running Windows XP and a laptop with Windows 7.

I created a folder and shared this one with both (or three) accounts.

I created an underlying folder (no need to share, says the help) but it is not visible on the other PCs, so I've shared it to both accounts.

Is this sharing necessary for every simple new folder?

Comment: No, an folder and all it's subfolder will be synced automatically.

Comment: @HackToHell It's possible to activate selective syncing in Dropbox preferences.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, but he did not explicitly do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have activated "selective syncing" under Advanced Preferences all files and folder inside your shared folder should be visible in all the other computers connected to the shared folder.

Maybe the issue is just to wait for the new folder to be uploaded or if something is weird, you terminate and restart the dropbox process.